# GET method returning empty

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

Good night, I'm developing a WebApi, I'm using the code-first approach, for that I used the entity framework 6.0.1, in my project I have the following classes PersonController.cs, Configurations.cs (where I insert the data manually for now) and my Person class, I'm using Postman to simulate the request, I looked for some examples here on the site but none equivalent to mine, if anyone can help me thank you.

**PersonController.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using WebApi.Models;
using WebApi.Contexto;

namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    public class PersonController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly Context contexto = new Context();
        [Route("api/person")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult getAll(string search)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
                search = "";
            }
            var list = contexto.People.Where(x => x.firstName.Contains(search) || x.lastName.Contains(search));

            return Ok(list);

        } 
     }
}
```

**Configurations.cs**

```
namespace WebApi.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;
    using WebApi.Models;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<WebApi.Contexto.Context>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(WebApi.Contexto.Context context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.

            context.People.Add(new Person { firstName = "Andrew ", lastName = "Teste", id = 1, birthDate = new DateTime(2021, 01, 31) });
           
        }
    }
}
```

**Person.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApi.Models
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime birthDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact URL you are hitting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to inform you, my error was found in the database connection string, it did not have the parameter:

`Integrated Security = True;`

Thanks to all for your help

Answer (score 0):

The search argument is null when you call the api

A work a round for this is to create a simple model or class
like

```
public class Query
{
   public string Search {get;set;}
}
```

and change your method into

```
public IHttpActionResult getAll([FromBody]Query query)
{
        var search = query.Search;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        {
            search = "";
        }

        var list = contexto.People.Where(x => x.firstName.Contains(search) || 
        x.lastName.Contains(search));

        return Ok(list);

}
```

Your Postman payload should be like

```
{
   "search":"a"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the parameter in [HttpGet] attribute, so your method parameter isnt actually getting your query string.

try

```
[HttpGet("{search}")]
```

or

```
public IHttpActionResult GetAll([FromQuery] string search)
```

Comment: I tried to do this but it returns this error

CS1729: 'HttpGetAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Comment: @JheimisMarques Are you using .NET Core or Framework?

Comment: @SoyDuck likely thinks you are on Core.

Comment: If hes on aspnet framework then maybe try `public IHttpActionResult GetAll([FromQuery] string search)`

Comment: tbf no one should be using framework for any new projects in 2021.